# How to make sure script is always running?

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I have 4 scripts in crontab that start on server boot. After 12 hours or so, some throw an exception and stop running. At that point, I want my server to just start the script again, so each script is always running.

I can run:

```
ps ax | grep python
```

And I see which one it usually is that stops running.

Comment: Do you have something against a third party software ? If not, i was thinking about Monit, that can monitor processes and restart them if they are down

Comment: Which Linux distribution? This is much easier on, e.g. Fedora and CentOS 7 than on Ubuntu or Debian.

Comment: CentOS 6 64Bits

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942146/self-restarting-daemon-in-python-in-nix-system

Comment: Maybe you can give supervisord (http://supervisord.org/) a chance. This little tool will restart your app, script, whatever after a crash.

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks that you are trying to solve a wrong problem here.

If your script acts as a daemon and needs to be running all the time, then it shouldn't crash periodically and expect to be restarted. Of course, unexpected crashes can happen, and yes, there are tools to monitor and restart services when they fail. However, if some service is crashing for you once or twice a day, then you better look what's wrong with it, instead of simply restarting it and pretending that it's fine.

If your script runs as a batch job and for some reason can't complete it's task, then again, it shouldn't just throw an exception, exit and wait to be restarted.

Find a reason why your script crashes and fix it. Use monitoring software to restart it, if unexpected failure happens, but not as a fix to a periodical crash.

Answer (score -1):

The solution you're are looking for calls watchdog. BTW. Linux uses a watchdog deamon, too, to ensure services are up and running.

A Discussion about it and fragments of solutions for scripts can be found here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55318/watchdog-script-to-keep-an-application-running

4 You to know and Steps to solve the problem:
Your scripts should write an pid file.
Inside the script:

```
echo $$ >PIDFILE
```

Maybe you may interact with semaphores like, to stop it on demand without killing it.

```
if [ -f sript.stop ] ; then
   exit
fi
```

Whatchdog as separate script started in cron once per minute and should do following:

Take the content of the pidfile and check is there a valid process running. !Attention, PID and Prozess to the runfile should match. Don't kill a Prozess started later on with maybe the same PID... or matching PID 334 could also match 52334 or 53342.. don't step into this traps.

If it's not running, delete the pidfile and start the script again.
This simple function could also be included to the script.

But as grekaius said, try to find out the reasen, why the script stops. 
In case of some Java application ... it is quite normal, a process may die.